# Transporter:Elasticsearch1.7 unknown parameter [refresh]

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I want to sync MongoDB database with Elasticsearch1.7. For which I created replication set of my db using following command:

```
$ sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --replSet rs0
```

I have configured transporter 0.1.0 and I run my transporter using following command:

```
$ ./transporter run --config ./test/config.yaml ./test/application.js
```

config.yaml

```
api:
   interval: 10s
nodes:
  localmongo:
    type: mongo
    uri: mongodb://localhost/mydb
    tail: true
  es:
    type: elasticsearch
    uri: http://192.168.x.xx:9200/
  timeseries:
    type: influx
    uri: influxdb://root:root@localhost:8086/compose
  debug:
    type: file
    uri: stdout://
  foofile:
    type: file
    uri: file:///tmp/foo
```

So when I try to delete one of the document from mongo it is reflected in mongo collection(I have replication enabled i.e oplogs have been configured as well as I can see the record being deleted in the transporter console) but after this it causes following exception at transporter console and due to this elastic search is not in sync with MongoDB.

> transporter: CRITICAL: elasticsearch error (2015-08-11
>   17:36:31.408666556 +0530 IST: Error
>   [IllegalArgumentException[Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown
>   parameter [refresh]]] Status [500] [500])

How can I fix this?